# How to access self managed kubernetes cluster from my local using kubectl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl

I am running a self managed kubernetes cluster on AWS EC2 instances( not EKS). I've used kubeadm to do the setup
The master and worker nodes are in public subnet and have public IPs.
I have set kube config in the worker and master nodes and I am able to run kubectl commands from the nodes, but I want to be able to run it from my local linux machine.

I have kubectl installed on my local and have copied over the kube config to ./kube/config in my local.

But when I run the kubectl command i get the error
$ kubectl get nodes
`E0929 12:04:43.319775   26908 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.227:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.227:6443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Now I know that this -  10.0.1.227 ,is the private IP of my master node and I cant connect to that from my local.

I tried by replacing the private ip with public ip of my master node(dumb solution I know) but it didn't work. got this error

```
E0929 11:26:50.902035   25572 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://3.110.130.136:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.0.1.227, not 3.110.130.136
```

Guessing cert in kube config is not generated for the public ip

FYI, port 6443 is open to all IPs in the security group.

How do I make this work?

Comment: What error did you get with using the public ip?

Comment: @Thomas 
I got this 
E0929 11:26:50.855338   25572 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://3.110.130.136:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.0.1.227, not 3.110.130.136
E0929 11:26:50.902035   25572 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://3.110.130.136:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.0.1.227, not 3.110.130.136

guessing that the cert present in the kube config is not valid for this ip

Answer (score 1):

When initializing the Kubernetes Cluster with `kubeadmin`, you specified option `--apiserver-advertise-address` as the Private IP, so the certificate in the `~/.kube/config` file only authenticates for this IP.
To be able to use the `kubectl` command from local with Public IP you can do the following:

1. Copy the K8S config file from `master node` to local and put it in the path `~/.kube/config`
2. Open `~/.kube/config` file and change the Private IP in the `server` to Public IP
3. When using the `kubectl` command you will need to add the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` option. Example:

   ```
   kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify get pods
   ```

This is an easy and quick way or a better solution is to add your `Public IP` to the kubernetes config file to be able to use multiple IPs. You can follow the instructions below:
https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9506/31538

Comment: This just worked perfectly! Thanks